# Почему программа компилируется, хотя конструкторы удалены и скрыты?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

По идее данный код компилироваться не должен, ибо конструкторов, которые может использовать main попросту нет. Однако компилятор MSVS2017 успешно выполняет данный код(хотя статический и анализатор кода ругается). Отсюда вопрос: как это происходит. Если всё же создать конструктор копирования и/или конструктор перемещения и  попытаться пошагово выполнить код, то ни конструктор копирования ни конструктор перемещения не вызывается. Переменная а просто волшебным образом инициализируется.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(const A& other) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A& other) = delete;
    A(A&& other) = delete;
    A& operator=(A&& other) = delete;

    static A createA()
    {
        return A(++lastData);
    }

    int getData()const { return data; }
private:
    A(int a) : data{ a } {}
    int data;

    static int lastData;
};
int A::lastData = 0;

int main() 
{
    A a = A::createA();
    cout << a.getData();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это новые правила исключения копирования при инициализации и возвращении значений из функции. В этом коде создается всего один объект `A` в `main` инициализирующийся вызовом приватного конструктора в `createA`.

Comment: @VTT То есть компилятор просто решил, что тут можно выполнить подстановку ПРИВАТНОГО конструктора? И при этом не вызывать ожидаемые copy или move конструкторы? Это как вообще, ведь по-идее в copy/move контрукторах я могу делать что-то помимо самого копирования/перемещения, например счётчик их вызовов какой-то вести. Но даже если всё так, как тогда можно заставить компилятор вызывать copy/move конструкторы при возврате из функции?

Comment: Да, стандарт разрешает игнорировать даже имеющие побочные эффекты copy / move конструкторы. Заставить вызвать copy/move конструкторы при возврате из функции (как написано в этом примере, то бишь без доп переменных) теперь никак нельзя. Новые правила предписывают откладывать материализацию временных объектов как можно дальше, до того момента, когда потребуется `glvalue`. А в этом примере это происходит только когда добиваемся до `a`.

Comment: `A(++lastData)` является prvalue и не приводит к созданию какого-либо объекта само по себе. Значение, возвращаемое `createA` тоже является prvalue и не приводит к созданию какого-либо объекта само по себе. А вот `a` уже будет lvalue и вызовет создание объекта.

Comment: @VTT прикольно, спасибо за подробное объяснение

Comment: Чтобы увидеть, что констукторы копирования и перемещения у вас точно удалены - поменяйте возвращаемое значение функции createA на ссылку (предварительно сделав объект статическим). Тогда у вас действительно не откомпилируется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статический метод-член класса имеет доступ к `private` конструктору, поэтому с этой стороны всё ок. Копирующий конструктор начиная с C++17 тут не нужен, поэтому тоже всё ок.

Comment: И за что минус?

Comment: Наверное потому, что полторы строчки не тянут на полноценный ответ?

Comment: @VTT почему вы так считаете? Что я не указал?

Comment: @tim bars необязательно, зависит от компилятора. Просто с 17 стандарта пропуск копирования обязателен по стандарту, хотя он делался и раньше

Comment: @digitalpower стоит добавить, что это называется copy elision.